# How can I change the size of the text in Word Press

Tags: functions

I have updated WordPress to the newest version. But due to compatibility issues, I need your help.

How can I change the font size of each text? What I'm doing right now is using some kinds of buttons on the bar in the image.

[image].

This question could be a duplicate, but could someone please help me....

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is exactly `the text` you want to change font size? You should mark it on your image.

Comment: Ahmm...thank you first for your comment. After having Jared's answer, I tought I need to learn html. css, in order to "control" the wordpress more effectively. Thank you.

Comment: I am sorry I am beginning to doubt. I used to use the very old version, which is 3.6.1, and when I updated, and after searching of "how to change the font size", then we have to go to the text side, like,<span style=”font-size:150%”>フォントサイズ150%の場合</span>, I don't know what was the problem with me, it didn't work anyway.....

Comment: Yes, and a site says the newest version has only 6 font sizes! ( To be controlled by the bar underneath the B or slanting I! What is wrong with the newest version!

Comment: So what're font sizes you're wanting to change, from 1 to 6? And you need to change it on admin screen only or both admin and public?

Comment: No, what I would like to do is, to change the size of the font arbitrarily ( of a specific one word etc, ) This newest version is not **new**! - - - -

Comment: Did you switch to `Text` editor before adding the code?

Comment: Yes. I did. Since I am not familiar with html, however, since I am speaking English and the "meaning of the code" could be unsetstandable to me I think. Thank you for your comment anyway.

Comment: So the only possibility is you use `”` instead `"`. Try `<span style="font-size:150%">フォントサイズ150%の場合</span>` in your `Text` editor and see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, remember that html is for adding meaning and css appearance.

If you want to change the text size for sematic reasons, like *"this text is a subsection title"* or *"this sentence is very important"*, I would advice you not to use `<span style="font-size: xx">`. It's a better practice for those cases to use `<strong>`, `<em>` or a proper heading tag and then change your theme's css to customize its appearance up to your likings.

If it's not for semantic but for presentational reasons, you are ok with `<span style="font-size: xx">`.

To make it easier, you can use the following code to add a new button to the text editor that will let you choose the font size without having to hardcode it each time.

[image]

Just copy the code to a new file, save it as `show-font-size-button-in-editor.php` and install and activate it as a plugin. Alternatively you can copy the `function` and `add_filter` to your theme's `functions.php` file.

```
<?php

    /*
        Plugin Name: Show font size button in editor
        Description: Adds a font size selector to the TinyMCE first tools row
        Version: 0.1
        Author: WPSE
        Author URI: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/225895/how-can-i-change-the-size-of-the-text-in-word-press
    */

    defined( 'ABSPATH' ) or die( 'Method not allowed.' );

    function wpse225895_show_font_size_button_in_editor( $buttons ) {

        array_unshift ( $buttons, 'fontsizeselect' );

        return $buttons;

    }

    add_filter( 'mce_buttons', 'wpse225895_show_font_size_button_in_editor', 10, 1 );

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can edit your theme's stylesheet (style.css) to change the font size for each of the headings and the paragraph element to your liking. Then you can select the heading that fits your needs in your text editor. To do this most easily, hover over the "Appearance" tab in your WordPress Admin, click "Editor," select your "Stylesheet" (aka "style.css") from the right side of the screen, and make the adjustments there. You have 6 headers, and you can adjust each like this:

```
h6 { font-size: 14px;}
```

The number following the "h" specifies which heading, and the number preceding the "px" specifies the size in pixels.

Then, as mentioned before, just select the heading that you wish to use, now having your updated font sizes.

You should use a child theme if you update your theme and want to preserve your changes. More information about those is available here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

Comment: What do you mean by `stylesheet.css` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can change font size of header and paragraph text by editing/adding custom CSS  to your stylesheet in Theme Root folder as `(wordpress/wp-content/themes/your-theme/style.css)`.

```
h1 { font-size: 24px;}
h2 { font-size: 22px;}
h3 { font-size: 18px;}
h4 { font-size: 16px;}
h5 { font-size: 12px;}
h6 { font-size: 10px;}
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Please don't add links if those are not related to answer.